# Integration $\int{x^3\over x^8+3}dx$

Tags: integration

I have a problem with this integral:

$$\int{x^3\over x^8+3}dx$$

I try to substitute $x^4$, but I have no idea how continue. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using $\tan^{-1}$?

Comment: wolframalpha.com has a great feature that will walk you through the steps of relatively simple integrals like this.  Just click "step-by-step solution" once you [have entered the integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E3%2F%28x%5E8+%2B+3%29).  Unfortunately you have to sign up for a free account to see the steps now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t=x^4$, then $dt=4x^3\,dx$, and

$$\int\frac{x^3}{x^8+3}\,dx=\int\frac{dt}{4(t^2+3)}$$

Let $t=\sqrt3u$, then $dt=\sqrt3\,du$, and

$$\int\frac{dt}{4(t^2+3)}=\int\frac{\sqrt3\,du}{12(u^2+1)}=\frac{\sqrt3}{12}\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{12}\arctan u+C=\frac{\sqrt3}{12}\arctan\frac{\sqrt3x^4}{3}+C$$